# Finding the max of a function using $f(x)=L(x)-E(x)$ where $L(x)$ is linear and $E(x)$ is exponential

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, maxima-minima

Take this problem, which was on a younger friend's recent AP Precalc test:

<sub>(note that this test was given by an online provider called "AP Classroom". I highly doubt that this was tested beforehand)</sub>

> 20. In the $xy$-plane, the graphs of a linear function $L$ and the exponential function $E$ both pass through the points $(0,2)$ and $(1,6)$. The function $f$ is given by $f(x)=L(x)-E(x)$. What is the maximum value of $f$?

Here is my friend's attempt at solving this:

1. Tackling $L(x)$

This is really easy to do. It can be noticed that due to rise/run, and since linear functions are defined by $mx+b$, we can see that it is intentional that $L(x)=4x+2$

2. Tackling $E(x)$

This is where there are multiple ways to represent the function, because apparently it wasn't mentioned whether this had to be in the form $ab^{x+c}+d$ or $ax^b+c$. My friend chose $E(x)=5^x+1$ because it satisfied both of the boundaries, and got that the max. of $f(x)$ was $\approx0.777$. (found through Desmos since it's allowed to be used on these tests)

Here are the options, which I intentionally didn't show beforehand:$$\begin{align}(a)&\quad0.007\\(b)&\quad0.172\\(c)&\quad0.54\\(d)&\quad1.002\end{align}$$Yep. Those are the only options. As you might have noticed, $0.777$ isn't on there. So, my friend randomly guessed (d), which turned out to be incorrect, with the correct answer apparently being (b). So my question is:

#### How is (b) 0.172 the correct answer?

Comment: That's weird - that question is definitely confusing. To me $5^x + 1$ and $2 \cdot 3^x$ seem like equally good candidates for $E(x)$. I have an observation: if
you let $E(x) = A (\sqrt 2)^x + B$ for the appropriate constants $A$, $B$, I get
that the maximum value of $f$ is $0.17299848063...$. (basically found by optimising the base of the exponential to get close to $0.172$). Technically to three decimal places that ought to be $0.173$ though.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen If I've done my math correctly then if somehow your observation was logically deduced, then it could be deduced that $A=4+4\sqrt2\implies B=-2-4\sqrt2$, which would have been gotten through noticing that $A+B=2,A\sqrt2+B=6$ due to the restrictions, but that's assuming we knew that $E(x)=A(\sqrt2)^x+B$ already. Edit 2: Also I agree that it (b) really ought to be 0.173 due to rounding, this is also confirmed by Desmos

Comment: Indeed! I was a bit unclear, sorry - my observation was purely obtained by working backwards from the solution $0.172$ to see what function of the form $Ak^x + B$ would possibly lead to that answer. I calculate that $k = 1.4099605874886516..$ would give an answer of $0.1715$, and $k = 1.4127973161049536..$ would give $0.1725$. $k = 1.411378218718823..$ would give exactly $0.172$. I just noticed that these numbers look sort of close to $\sqrt 2$. This is far from an explanation of what the intended answer was though - I'm as mystified as you are!

Answer (score 1):

The question is ill-defined. Exponential functions have three degrees of freedom. Any exponential function can be written as $$E(x) = a(b)^x + c.$$
Note that $$ab^{x+c} + d = ab^xb^c +d = \tilde{a}b^x + d,$$ where $\tilde{a} = a\cdot b^c$. Thus your first description of an exponential does not need the $+c$ in the exponent. (Further, your second description of an exponential is written as a polynomial, not an exponential. Perhaps there's a typo?)

Therefore, in order to get a unique description of a polynomial, at least 3 points would need to be provided.